# Different methods in class dont modify class variable

Tags: python, class

I want to read a CSV file that's a monthly statement and sort by merchant. I parse each day as a list in the format `['Completed Date ', ' Description ', ' Paid Out ', ' Paid In ', ' Exchange Out', ' Exchange In', ' Balance ', ' Category', ' Notes']`.

The class I wrote, which so far only has a method to sort by merchant( `Description` ):

```
class Spent:
    merchants = dict()
    entry = [] # the list I want to check

    def SortByMerchant(self, dailyEntry):
        self.entry = dailyEntry

        if self.entry[1] in self.merchants.keys():
            self.merchants[self.entry[1]] += int(self.entry[2])
        else:
            try:
                self.merchants[self.entry[1]] = int(self.entry[2])
            except ValueError:
                pass

    def PrintMerchant(self):
        for merchant in self.merchants:
            print(merchant)
```

Main file for the class instantiation

```
import csv
import SpentClass

csvFile = open("statement.csv")
csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';')

Instance = SpentClass.Spent()

for line in csvReader:
    Instance.SortByMerchant(line)
    
Instance.PrintMerchant()
```

`PrintMerchant` does not work and just displays an empty dict() and so does `SortByMerchant` if I add a print statement. How can I make sure that the variables inside my class instance get updated?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `self.`, it refers to an object variable, not to a class variable.

You should use `<class name>.` instead, for example in your case, `Spent.`.

Having said that, reading your code, I'm not so sure that using class variables is what you want here to begin with; it looks more like you can simply use object variables for your specific goal.

Comment: I tried replacing `self.` with `Spent.` for the variables(not the function arguments) and it still doesn't work. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by class variables and object variables. I only have one instance of this class that I plan to use. This is [how I'd implement it in C++](https://godbolt.org/z/5rb5o7). I instantiate a `Spent` object and all subsequent calls to `SortByMerchant` will update the same `merchant` in C++.